# Cassandra Automatic failover delay when a node fails

Tags: c#, cassandra, nosql

I am new to Cassandra.

I have created 2 cassandra 2.1 nodes on two Debian VMware machines. In asp.net mvc I used datastax driver 2.1.5,don't really have any issues but when I shutdown or disable the network on one of the nodes, the application seems to have 5 or 10 second delay to automatically connect other nodes.

when two nodes are up, query runs in c# 
**00:00:00.0620413**  seconds 
and when a node is down query runs in
 **00:00:10.0607187** seconds. Every refresh page delay 10 second, when two node are running, the query executes in below 1 second.

my code:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoints("192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.")
            .WithRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.Instance)
            .WithReconnectionPolicy(new FixedReconnectionPolicy(0, 10))
            .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(
                new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy()))
            .Build();
```

---

my config on tow node:
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:
  - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
    parameters:
         - seeds:  "192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2"
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

in node 1:
listen_address: 192.168.0.1
rpc_address:192.168.0.1

in node 2:
listen_address: 192.168.0.2
rpc_address:192.168.0.2

---

my keyspace:
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace
WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2 };

Comment: Enable the driver logs to check what is happening, also check the cassandra logs of the "live" node.

Answer (score 1):

What is your consistency level? If your consistency level is 1. You should see failures as one of the node is down on 50% of the cases. But because of the retry policies in the datastax driver it mostly is obtaining the data after a read timeout.

But for read timeout to occur it first has to send a request to the down node, hence i think the increased latency.

As the default read timeout is 10 seconds, you are seeing a delay of 10. I would say you should reduce this if this is a common case for you.

**How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete**
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

Comment: hi. tnx for your answer. consistency is 1, i change bellow parameter, but everything is like before.                                 read_request_timeout_in_ms, range_request_timeout_in_ms, write_request_timeout_in_ms, counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms, cas_contention_timeout_in_ms, request_timeout_in_ms.

Comment: What did you change the value too?

Comment: read_request_timeout_in_ms=100 , range_request_timeout_in_ms=100 , write_request_timeout_in_ms=100 , counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=100 , cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=100 , request_timeout_in_ms=100.        but query runs in c# 00:00:00.0620413 seconds and when a node is down query runs in 00:00:10.0607187 seconds.

Comment: Did you restart your nodes after you made the changes? cassandra.yaml file changes need a restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms. The problem turned out to be the broadcast_rpc_address specified in the cassandra.yaml file on the two nodes. It was pointing at another cluster. The solution for me was to change this IP to the public IP of one of the nodes in the current cluster.